# (IRC) How do I find out when a user was last seen in a channel?

Tags: irc, xchat

I use XChat.
How do I find out when a user last logged into the channel or was last there?

`/!seen [user-nick]` didn't work. It said `!seen` isn't a command.
I don't want my query to be visible to others.

How do I do it then?

Comment: I don't know of any commands for specific channels, but only of 'last seen' in the server. Otherwise, you could have a bot and ask it directly, depending on what commands are available on the bot.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On networks with NickServ, you can use INFO command. So, if you want to find out when a user 'Jerry' was last online, you can do:

> /msg nickserv info Jerry

If they're online, you can whois them, like:

> /whois NickName

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write !seen in the channel you can usually pm the bot with something like:

> !seen #channel
>   nickname

Answer (score 0):

On Freenode IRC network there are some channels where you can use semicolon:

```
;;seen NickName
```

The query will be visible to others if you do it in the channel itself. But you can ask in private chat gribble if it is installed (Freenode's Supybot).

Comment: `;; Nickname` isn't a global command. It will only work if there's a bot configured to do that in the channel you're doing it in.

Comment: @AmalMurali: You're right. Gonna edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your answer. Feel free to revert it back if you think I changed too much.